# data.table - group size relative to total number of rows

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for a concise data.table solution for the following:

I want to add a new column "ratio" that is the size of each group in relation to the total number of rows of the dataframe.

We can do it as follows: Add a column "N" that is constant and contains the total number of rows. Then group by the variable "group" and divide the group size by the total size:

```
df = data.table(group=c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 3)))
df[, N:=.N][, ratio := .N/N, group][,N:=NULL]
```

with the desired outcome:

```
   group ratio
1:   a   0.4
2:   a   0.4
3:   b   0.6
4:   b   0.6
5:   b   0.6
```

But is there a better way without adding/removing the dummy column?

Comment: df[,ratio:=.N/nrow(df),by="group"]

Comment: It's a long-standing FR of mine to have a "global" version of `.N`. In retrospect, we should have used `.n` for `nrow`-by-group and `.N` for `nrow`-overall. The issue now is just finding a good alias for "global nrow". See here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1206

Comment: @Prahlad's comment clearly answers my question as I put it. So feel free to formulate an answer. Actually I was hoping for a global version of `.N` as @MichaelChirico suggests. At least now I know that it does not exist yet. Thank you both for the feedback.